# MQTT java.io.EOFException in Android 7.0

Tags: android, tcp, mqtt

In my android application, I am usering MQTT to connect with MQTT Server. It's running smoothly in android **with version  < 7.0** with many years. However, the tcp connection is always interrupted in **android with verion >= 7.0**, it's reconnecting and interrupted. 
    All of the exception is as following :

> 07-26 18:20:35.049 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err:  (32109) - java.io.EOFException
>   07-26 18:20:35.050 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:148)
>   07-26 18:20:35.050 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>   07-26 18:20:35.051 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.EOFException
>   07-26 18:20:35.051 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err:     at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:270)
>   07-26 18:20:35.052 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:66)
>   07-26 18:20:35.052 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err:     at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:111)
>   07-26 18:20:35.053 24517-26973/com.XXXX.XXXX W/System.err:   ... 1 more

[image]

The exception comes from here:
   [image]

Any one can help me?

Comment: Please do not post images of code and errors, it makes it impossible to search for and the error message is too small to read. Please add the text and use the options to format them.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I  have posted the error message in text, and the excepiton message is indeed very small I have catched.